# How do I include external testing projects in my main Project saved on Github

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, github

Not sure how to phrase this, I have an ASP.netcore web app with Unit and integration tests.
These live outside of the Main Project folder.

[image]

They are in the same solution.

[image]

RolesForAssesment is the main project folder. The others are tests.

How do I include these external folders into my GitHub Repo for the RolesForAssesment
Project.

I can drag the Master folder containing these 4 folders into VS Code and then generate a new github account and it will work. But surely it can be done in Visual Studio as well.

At the moment all I can save is the RolesForAssessment solution without the tests.

Thanks

Comment: Where is the solution file located?

Comment: In the RolesForAssessment folder.

Comment: is it not possible to move the test project folders inside the solution folder?

Comment: Yeah, but thats a code smell. They should be outside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I solved it. You have to name your new projects with the SolutionName.NewProjectName

Then Github will update it. So for mine its RolesForAssessment.Integrationtests